# Full wave bridge rectifier circuit in multisim

Tags: multisim

I need to get this laboratory report done but I am stuck in this multisim exercise where the circuit I have produced should be a functional full wave bridge rectifier with a simple resistive filter but it is only reducing the magnitude of the output sinusoid as opposed to actually doing a full wave rectification.

[image: This is the circuit which is supposed to act as a full wave rectifier]

I made it based on this diagram provided to me by my lecturer:

[image]

Can anyone pin point the reason why this circuit is not acting as a full wave bridge rectifier?

Thanks,
Simon.

Comment: Yeah thanks guys both answers helped me get the output I needed in the end. The sheets I printed originally had a 1V pk value and later on it was updated to 10v after I had printed it for my own use. But I now have a thorough comprehension of this simple circuit as I was initially expecting to see a typical full wave rectified circuit. After researching online I discovered the purpose of the capacitor as a 'smoothing' capacitor giving a pulsating D.C. output. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your voltage source V1 has a peak voltage of just 1V, your lecturer had a voltage source of 10V. In a bridge rectifier circuit the current has to flow through 2 diodes which will have a voltage drop of about 0.7V each, ie 1.4V. So I would not expect to get any voltage from your circuit at all.

Also, you have put the ground reference at the wrong point. I would put it at the R1 / R3 junction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have grounded your AC supply. The AC supply should be floating, with the negative of your bridge rectifier grounded, given that you have grounded the other terminal of your measuring device.